# dryer won't start

Tags: dryer

When I set the dryer to the setting I want and push the "start" button, the dryer just "clicks", it does not start, the drum does not turn, nothing. In order to stop the clicking I have to turn the setting knob to off.  It is a Kenmore gas dryer #71202

Comment: Clicks sounds like like a relay/solenoid not connecting.  Google your make and model for a wiring diagram.

Comment: Does it work on some of the settings you don't want?

Comment: Are you holding the button *long enough*?  It's not a tap, you need to hold it for 500-2000ms.

Comment: Yes, I'm holding down the start button long enough.

Comment: No it doesn't work on any setting.

Comment: It could be something simple. Push and hold the door close than start.

Comment: did you pay the gas bill?